# Protect data in transit when two lambda communicate via AWS SNS (simple notification service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, serverless

I am working on serverless architecture using AWS lambda where multiple modules/lambdas communicate via SNS (simple notification service).

Due to compliance requirement that data in transit should be secure and encrypted, do I need to do that manually or SNS natively supports it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just came to know that we can enable ssl in all SNS requests by setting sslEnabled flag to true (in case of node sdk). `this.sns = new AWS.SNS({ sslEnabled: true });`

Answer (score 0):

AWS services communication between them are secure by design because happens within the Amazon’s network.

**SNS documentation**

> Amazon SNS provides access control mechanisms to ensure that topics and messages are secured against unauthorized access. Topic owners can set policies for a topic that restrict who can publish or subscribe to a topic. Additionally, topic owners can ensure that notifications are encrypted by specifying that the delivery mechanism must be HTTPS.

**Hope it helps**

Comment: Additionally, topic owners can ensure that notifications are encrypted by specifying that the delivery mechanism must be HTTPS. - As per my understanding, this is valid only in case of https subscribers. In my case subscriber is a Lambda.

Comment: @VipinGoel  an invocation from SNS to Lambda is executed through API calls for sure.  Those API calls make https requests internally, so your data travels from one service to others encrypted by default.

Comment: You may be right, but is there any proof to validate this statement.

Comment: Just came to know that we can enable ssl in all SNS requests by setting sslEnabled flag to true (in case of node sdk).